# Automate the specific format generation based on input in rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a form of slip for payment to Govt. (call it "Challan"). Based on the input in the rows, the challan form fill-up can be automated. I want to keep the filled-in Challan form (each size a page) in a separate sheet from the input sheet. I want to print Challan in page number corresponding to the row number of the inputs sheet. I could link the variable cells of the Challan with the inputs in the input sheets. Now I need a command button at the end of each row of the input sheet to give a print/populate command to print/populate the Challan form (I have used Copy Range VBA code) in the nth page number in Challan sheet based on nth row of the input sheet. I couldn't link the nth row of the input sheet and nth page of the Challan sheet with VBA. Is there any easy option to do this or can we develop the VBA code to do so?

Comment: You can develop the VBa code to do what you want

Comment: May you please suggest the VBA code?

Comment: Can you clearly state or show what you're trying to do? It's not very clear. See [ask] for more tips and [edit] your question with info